# Will an ARC application run on iOS 3.2?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Apple's documentation says ARC applications will run on iOS 4.0 or newer. Will an ARC app run successfully on iOS 3.2?

Comment: The answer is in the question

Comment: @gcamp: you'd think so, but not necessarily. I've run into situations where the Apple documentation says a given method is available only from a certain iOS version, but in fact the function was available in earlier versions (example: the method for getting a thumbnail from a contact photo is documented for iOS 4.1, but still works in iOS 4.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it runs on iOS 3.2 for iPad at least. I've encountered this for other things, where the documentation says it only works for such-and-such a version, but it works for earlier versions at well.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the "[Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)":

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit
>   applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not
>   supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Comment: Have you tried running an ARC app on a 3.2 device (I don't have access to one myself)? My question is not so much about what the documentation says, but about whether ARC apps will actually run or not on a 3.2 device. The doc says it's not supported for earlier iOS versions, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it won't actually work.